# CPS in curried languages

Tags: haskell, ocaml, continuations, currying, continuation-passing

How does [CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) in curried languages like lambda calculus or Ocaml even make sense? Technically, all function have one argument. So say we have a CPS version of addition in one such language:

```
cps-add k n m = k ((+) n m)
```

And we call it like

```
(cps-add random-continuation 1 2)
```

This is then the same as:

```
(((cps-add random-continuation) 1) 2)
```

I already see two calls there that aren't tail calls and in reality a complexly nested expression, the `(cps-add random-continuation)` returns a value, namely a function that consumes a number, and then returns a function which consumes another number and then delivers the sum of both to that `random-continuation`. But we can't work around this value returning by simply translating this into CPS again, because we can only give each function one argument. We need to have at least two to make room for the continuation and the 'actual' argument.

Or am I missing something completely?

Comment: Maybe I'm the only person who didn't know what CPS meant in this context. :-) Or maybe not. If not: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style

Comment: Note that CPS comes in two forms:  It's either a paradigm (e.g. Cont) or an implementation detail (e.g. Codensity).  In the former of course it turns every function into a function-function, i.e. it adds another argument.  In the latter it's just how it's implemented under the hood.  Some languages use CPS all over the place, while providing a non-CPS interface, Scheme being the canonical example.  But then most Scheme implementations go ahead and expose that implementation detail as a language feature called call/cc.

Answer (score 10):

Since you've tagged this with Haskell, I'll answer in that regard: In Haskell, the equivalent of doing a CPS transform is working in the `Cont` monad, which transforms a value `x` into a higher-order function that takes one argument and applies it to `x`.

So, to start with, here's 1 + 2 in regular Haskell: `(1 + 2)` And here it is in the continuation monad:

```
contAdd x y = do x' <- x
                 y' <- y
                 return $ x' + y'
```

...not terribly informative. To see what's going on, let's disassemble the monad. First, removing the `do` notation:

```
contAdd x y = x >>= (\x' -> y >>= (\y' -> return $ x' + y'))
```

The `return` function lifts a value into the monad, and in this case is implemented as `\x k -> k x`, or using an infix operator section as `\x -> ($ x)`.

```
contAdd x y = x >>= (\x' -> y >>= (\y' -> ($ x' + y')))
```

The `(>>=)` operator (read "bind") chains together computations in the monad, and in this case is implemented as `\m f k -> m (\x -> f x k)`. Changing the bind function to prefix form and substituting in the lambda, plus some renaming for clarity:

```
contAdd x y = (\m1 f1 k1 -> m1 (\a1 -> f1 a1 k1)) x (\x' -> (\m2 f2 k2 -> m2 (\a2 -> f2 a2 k2)) y (\y' -> ($ x' + y')))
```

Reducing some function applications:

```
contAdd x y = (\k1 -> x (\a1 -> (\x' -> (\k2 -> y (\a2 -> (\y' -> ($ x' + y')) a2 k2))) a1 k1))

contAdd x y = (\k1 -> x (\a1 -> y (\a2 -> ($ a1 + a2) k1)))
```

And a bit of final rearranging and renaming:

```
contAdd x y = \k -> x (\x' -> y (\y' -> k $ x' + y'))
```

In other words: The arguments to the function have been changed from numbers, into functions that take a number and return the final result of the entire expression, just as you'd expect.

**Edit**: A commenter points out that `contAdd` itself still takes two arguments in curried style. This is sensible because it doesn't use the continuation directly, but not necessary. To do otherwise, you'd need to first break the function apart between the arguments:

```
contAdd x = x >>= (\x' -> return (\y -> y >>= (\y' -> return $ x' + y')))
```

And then use it like this:

```
foo = do f <- contAdd (return 1)
         r <- f (return 2)
         return r
```

Note that this is really no different from the earlier version; it's simply packaging the result of each partial application as taking a continuation, not just the final result. Since functions are first-class values, there's no significant difference between a CPS expression holding a number vs. one holding a function.

Keep in mind that I'm writing things out in very verbose fashion here to make explicit all the steps where something is in continuation-passing style.

---

Addendum: You may notice that the final expression looks very similar to the de-sugared version of the monadic expression. This is not a coincidence, as the inward-nesting nature of monadic expressions that lets them change the structure of the computation based on previous values is closely related to continuation-passing style; in both cases, you have in some sense reified a notion of causality.

Comment: You did show how the continuation monad allows to elegantly formulate code that, once desugared, is the usual CPS-style program. But you did not handle currification, which seems to be the thing the OP wonders about : your function `contAdd` still takes two parameters in a curried style, from the start.

Comment: @gasche: How so? Everything is curried by default in Haskell, and I imagine this is pretty much how you'd do it if you wanted to hand-roll continuations in any other curried and typed functional language. EDIT: There's little reason to write `contAdd` any other way, because it never uses the continuation itself. But I see your point.

Comment: Shouldn't the second line in your definition of `foo` (`r <- contAdd (return 2)`) be `r <- f (return 2)` instead?

Comment: @ShinNoNoir: Of course it should be `f`. In fact, it is `f` and has always been `f`, the very idea of it saying `contAdd` there is inconceivable. Also, it has always been the case that we are at war with Oceania. (p.s. -- thanks for the catch)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : of course it makes sense, you can apply a CPS-transform directly, you will only have lots of cruft because each argument will have, as you noticed, its own attached continuation

In your example, I will consider that there is a `+(x,y)` uncurried primitive, and that you're asking what is the translation of

```
let add x y = +(x,y)
```

(This `add` faithfully represent OCaml's `(+)` operator)

`add` is syntaxically equivalent to

```
let add = fun x -> (fun y -> +(x, y))
```

So you apply a CPS transform¹ and get

```
let add_cps = fun x kx -> kx (fun y ky -> ky +(x,y))
```

If you want a translated code that looks more like something you could have willingly written, you can devise a finer transformation that actually considers known-arity function as non-curried functions, and tream all parameters as a whole (as you have in non-curried languages, and as functional compilers already do for obvious performance reasons).

¹: I wrote "*a* CPS transform" because there is no "one true CPS translation". Different translations have been devised, producing more or less continuation-related garbage. The formal CPS translations are usually defined directly on lambda-calculus, so I suppose you're having a less formal, more hand-made CPS transform in mind.

The good properties of CPS (as a *style* that program respect, and not a specific transformation into this style) are that the order of evaluation is completely explicit, and that all calls are tail-calls. As long as you respect those, you're relatively free in what you can do. Handling curryfied functions specifically is thus perfectly fine.

Remark : Your `(cps-add k 1 2)` version can also be considered tail-recursive if you assume the compiler detect and optimize that cps-add actually always take 3 arguments, and don't build intermediate closures. That may seem far-fetched, but it's the exact same assumption we use when reasoning about tail-calls in non-CPS programs, in those languages.

Comment: While I would subscribe to the solution of uncurried functions, as in, encoding the arguments that are the continuation and the 'actual' argument in one datum. I'm still not sure what the rest would say. As you said, all calls are tail calls, but in curried functions, not all calls are tail calls. In (cps-add k 1 2) there are two calls that are not tail calls but a nested expression.

Comment: @Lajla: What is your concern with tail calls? Is this a practical objection or a stylistic concern?

Comment: In my `add_cps` version, all calls are tail calls.

Comment: Yes, but to call, cps-add, you would invariably end up with having non-tail-calls at some point. It's more a theoretical than practical question for me. What is the real theoretical difference with allowing this and allowing just aribrary non-tail-calls.

Comment: @Lajla: You can always keep replacing values with functions that apply those values until the only non-tail-calls left are the ones wrapping primitive values. I'm not sure what else you expect, or how this differs from a language without currying.

Comment: Yeah, but you can say the same thing about any function which returns some other function. Say I for instance in Scheme have a compose function and I use `((compose square sqrt) 3)`, clearly not TCO style in lieu of (compose (lambda (foo) (foo 3)) square sqrt), but you can just as well say that this is a curried variant of a function which takes three arguments. Composes the first two, and then applies that to the third.

Comment: @Lajla: Huh? No, the whole point is that by doing those replacements, no function ever returns a function other than the ones wrapping primitives. Each function takes a single argument, which is itself a function that takes some value and returns the final result of the entire program. I'm really not sure what it is you're asking at this point.

Answer (score 0):

yes, technically all functions can be decomposed into functions with one method, however, when you want to use CPS the only thing you are doing is saying is that at a certain point of computation, run the continuation method.

Using your example, lets have a look. To make things a little easier, let's deconstruct cps-add into its normal form where it is a function only taking one argument.

(cps-add k) -> n -> m = k ((+) n m)

Note at this point that the continuation, k, is not being evaluated (Could this be the point of confusion for you?).

Here we have a method called cps-add k that receives a function as an argument and then returns a function that takes another argument, n.

((cps-add k) n) -> m = k ((+) n m)

Now we have a function that takes an argument, m.

So I suppose what I am trying to point out is that currying does not get in the way of CPS style programming. Hope that helps in some way.

Comment: But it does get away from it. Because the idea of CPS is that no function call ever returns a value and that no expression is complexly nested. This example nests expressions into another and function calls return values.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this should be a resolvable issue. 'Return' can mean a lot of different things and can be implemented in a lot of different ways. 'Calls' can be implemented with 'jmp's. At least in the case of primitive recursion, any function can be rewritten to use loops instead of recursion. I believe this can be generalized also. More discussion is welcome on this though.